# Bootstrap Vue table: column of buttons do not sort with the rest of the table

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have at bootstrap vue b-table with the following column/type assignments:

- (c1) *Include in Run*, checkbox
- (c2) *Name*, string
- (c3) *ID*, integer
- (c4) *Mode*, string
- (c5) *Target Type*, string
- (c6) *Angles On*, integer
- (c7) *Angles Off*, integer
- (c8) *Latitude*, float
- (c9) *Longitude*, float
- (c10) *Status*, string
- (c11) *Edit*, button (pops up a modal)

Most of the columns are 'sortable', however the *Edit* column does not sort with the rest of the table. The *Edit* column is a column of buttons which pop up a modal allowing the user to modify the fields of a row. When the table is sorted on a column and the row positions change, the edit remains rigidly assigned to the original row, resulting in the wrong row being modified.

I have tried making the *Edit* column 'sortable', but this had no effect.  The *Include in Run* column of checkboxes are sorting with the rest of the rows, but that pesky *Edit* column won't budge.  Below is the table defined in the template:

```html
<b-table bordered
         id="customTable"
         striped hover
         :items="this.mittTargets"
         class="fontSize"
         :fields="fields">
    <template v-slot:cell(selected)="row">
        <b-form-group>
            <input type="checkbox"
                   v-model="row.item.selected"
                   :id="row.item.ID"
                   class="fontSize"
                    @change="updateTargets(row.item)"/>
        </b-form-group>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:cell(actions)="row">
        <b-button size="sm"
                  @click="editModalConnect(row.item, row.index, $event.target)"
                  id="button-gradient"
                  v-b-tooltip.hover
                  title="single click">
             Edit
        </b-button>
    </template>
</b-table>
```

I appreciate any help I may get on this.

Comment: I don't have a solution off the top of my head, but you should know that because your button `id`s are set to the static string "button-gradient", all your buttons have the same `id`. This may be related to the problem.

Comment: Hm... I can't get a repro on this: <https://jsfiddle.net/wg9yb75v/>.

Comment: Thank you very much zooop98,  I changed id to class (as it should be), but that did not solve the problem.  However, you did get me thinking in the right direction.  The problem was not that the edit buttons did not sort with rest of the table, but that my modal was updating the row position based on the original order.  I solved it by adding a 'row_num' element to the object before creating the table, then having the modal reference that row number.